# HAProxy reqrep not replacing string in url

Tags: haproxy

We have deprecated some software which was available under http://localhost/test and is now available under http://localhost/app/testing. We are using `HAProxy 1.4`

Thus, I want via haproxy, to replace all urls containing `/test` with `/app/testing/`. I tried first with a `redirect prefix` in order to keep the query string, but `/test` wasn't removed from the url and had something like `/app/testing/test/?id=x`.

```
frontend all
    bind  0.0.0.0:80
    timeout client 86400000
    acl is_test path_beg /test
    redirect prefix /app/testing code 301 if is_test
```

Then used a `reqrep`, which seems to redirect to the new software, but the `/test` string in the url is never replaced.

```
frontend all
    bind  0.0.0.0:80
    timeout client 86400000
    reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /test[/]?(.*)  \1\ /app/testing/\2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since url rewriting isn't possible with version 1.4 and we didn't want to update HAProxy, we went on using `reqrep` and keeping the old link as is with

```
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /test[/]?(.*)  \1\ /app/testing/\2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
This works for me with your scenario on HAProxy 1.6

```
 acl test     path_beg -i /test
 http-request set-header         X-Location-Path %[capture.req.uri] if test
 http-request replace-header     X-Location-Path /test /app/testing if test
 http-request redirect location  %[hdr(X-Location-Path)] if test
 use_backend WHEREVER            if test
```

Comment: I'm using 1.4. Aren't there any differences?

Comment: I think what you are suggesting is not possible with 1.4

Answer (score 1):

Using `redirect prefix` is meant, going by the HAProxy examples, more for changing the hostname, but keeping the path. For example, http://apple.com/my/path could be redirected to http://orange.com/my/path with:

```
redirect prefix http://orange.com if apple
```

The HAProxy [1.4 docs](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.4/configuration.html#redirect%20prefix) say:

> With "redirect prefix", the "Location" header is built from the
>   concatenation of < pfx > and the complete URI path

To me, that suggests that you would expect whatever you put for the "prefix" will be prefixed to what was already in the path. That explains the behavior you were seeing. This is useful for changing to a new domain (e.g. from *apple.com* to *orange.com*), but keeping the original path (e.g. */my/path*).

You can switch to using `redirect location` to replace the entire URL. The following would redirect http://apple.com/my/path to http://orange.com/path:

```
redirect location http://orange.com/path if apple
```

UPDATE:

In the case where you want to change the URL, but keep the query string, use `reqirep` or `reqrep` to rewrite the URL, as you are doing, but also put a `redirect prefix` into the `frontend`. The URL will be rewritten *and then* the user will be redirected to it so they see it.

You might be able to set the "prefix" to "/". The HAProxy docs say:

> As a special case, if < pfx > equals exactly "/", then nothing is
>   inserted before the original URI. It allows one to redirect to the
>   same URL (for instance, to insert a cookie).

Using your code example, something like this:

```
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /test[/]?(.*)  \1\ /app/testing/\2
redirect prefix / code 301 if is_test
```

Comment: tried that, but `redirect location` doesn't keep the query string, which is the most important part to us

Comment: I added an update about combining the use of reqrep and redirect prefix.

Comment: still works as I mentioned in my question. it is redirected correctly but the url still stays the same. As I wrote in my answer, I don't think url rewritting is possible with v1.4 (at least that's what I read somewhere else)

Comment: Ah okay. Must be a limitation of 1.4.